# How to get Items in order with limit in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, mysql-variables

I have a table `Item ( id, itemType)`. `itemType` can be from 1-5.

I want to retrieve 2 items of each type using mysql.

I tried

```
select * from `item` ORDER BY `itemType` limit 2
```

which gives me 2 items order by type but I want 2 items of each type.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef83d/1

Comment: You can use "order by columnname limit"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below query, even i did not check it with data as I dont have sample data so if you get any issue then you can create a sqlfiddle, so that I can customize query as per you in #sql

```
SELECT x.id,x.type1 as 'Type'
FROM (SELECT t.*,
               CASE 
                 WHEN @type != t.type THEN @rownum := 1 
                 ELSE @rownum := @rownum + 1 
               END AS rank,
               @type := t.type AS 'type1'
          FROM item t
          JOIN (SELECT @rownum := NULL, @type := '') r     
      ORDER BY t.type,t.id) X
      WHERE x.rank<=2;
```

Even you can ordering based on top price or any other field.

Comment: This article helped. Thanks for sqlfiddle suggest, I'll do that next time.

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Comment: yes this blog also showing how you can achieve it, then why you posted your question here.

Comment: I kept searching after posting the question. Now, someone like me faces the same question can use this blog.

Comment: I added the sqlfiddle

Comment: if it works for you then you may accept it as answer by green tick :)